# React-Modal Unable to set position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-modal

I'm using react-modal, and I cannot find any way to successfully set the position of the Modal. I'm using inline styles per examples online, but they have no effect. I'm doing exactly what I see working in the codepen example on the react-modal site, but it doesn't work in my app. Something is obviously different, but I cannot see what it is.

This is how I'm rendering the Modal:

```
render: function() {
    return (
      <Modal
        bsSize={this.props.size}
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-lg"
        show={this.props.show}
        style={{ content : {top: '70%'}}}
        onHide={this.hideModal}>
        <Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-lg">{this.props.modalTitle}</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          {this.props.modalBody || this.modalBody}
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={this.hideModal}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.props.modalCallback}>{this.props.confirmButtonText}</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
```

I've tried many different values for the style property, but anything I set has no effect. I also tried without the `bsSize` property, and that didn't work either. I just need the top border of the content to be somewhat lower, because it is opened on top of another modal in the same position, and I want it to be visually apparent that there are two modals open on the page. I'm using react-modal 3.3.1.

Comment: Try  style={{ top: '70%'}} once and check

Comment: That worked. Thank you. But I'm also trying to set the width, and that has different results. I want to get a size between bsSize="large" and not specifying bsSize. So I set bsSize="large" and specify the style as style={{top: '20%', width: '80%'}}. The top is offset as I expect, but instead of reducing width to 80%, it shifts it 20% to the left, without changing the width. Setting width to 120% shifts it 20% to the right. Setting left and right doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to help provided on [this GitHub issue post](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1643), I got it to work as follows:

```
<Modal dialogClassName='custom-dialog'...>
```

CSS:

```
.custom-dialog {width:48% !important; top:20%;}
```

The piece I was missing was the need to override the width setting with `!important`. The width is relative to the viewport width, so I found a value by trial and error that gave me the desired percentage of the underlying Modal's width.

Comment: I'm not an expert in JS/CSS but this was really helpful, thanks!